# How do I lift my spirits after giving a bad examination paper today?

Tags: exams

I had my Mathematics paper today. Its of 90 marks. In the past, I have always scored 90 or at least 88. Today, the paper was extremely lengthly and I made a silly mistake in a question of 4 marks although I knew the answer perfectly well. I am sure other answers are correct. But I am feeling very depressed for failing my expectations. I have got my Science, Social Studies and English Paper in the next week. I think I will mess up in other papers too. I am afraid my classmates will tease me. I am afraid someone else will get full marks. How to lift my spirits?

Comment: Marks can be a fun competition against oneself. However, in actual career, marks play a smaller role than you would expect. I estimate the half-life of marks at completion of a degree to be 1-2 years, after that it will count what you have done since the degree. If the marks are not degree-relevant, the half-life is even shorter. So, take them seriously, but not too much so. Now, find out why you made the silly mistake; didn't you have time to do a final check? Were you giddy or overconfident? Once you find the reason, try to fix that for the next round. Mistakes happen, learn from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who has lived through this, the solution is to stop trying to be perfect and forgive yourself for making mistakes.  Classmates would tease me because I built up a shield of "perfection" to try to defend against criticism.  There's a big difference between setting goals for yourself and not allowing yourself to be human.  We're all human, including very smart people like yourself.

Try to turn the fear of someone else getting full marks into encouragement of others to get full marks.  I understand that many education systems around the world use rankings in classes for standing.  I did part of my education in such a system, and I understand how it leads to complex social implications.  The best approach is to encourage one another and whoever is on top that particular examination will be respected instead of envied.  The next examination, it may be another person, and that's ok.  By focusing on encouraging each other and being happy for each other's successes, you'll collectively raise your marks and achievements, which will server you much better later in life and your career than always being on top.  You will find that the opportunities in life, even in the most restrictive of harshly competitive academic environments, are not based solely on top grades, but rather a whole picture of the person.

You will NOT mess up the other papers because you clearly study hard and know the subjects.  Once you get into working on them, your spirits will lift themselves as you find your comfort zone in those topics that you know well.  You might even find that the previous slip up will help you with your creativity, which is even more important in Social Studies and English.

You'll look back in 10 or 20 years and everything will look different in retrospect.  Trust me.  I've done it myself. :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

- Perform service for others -- especially those who are less fortunate. Help at food bank, read books at children's hospital, play chess at local prison (I don't know if that last one is actually a thing). Helping others puts life in better perspective.
- Do something that raises endorphins. Run, lift weights, go climbing (especially indoors where you can achieve top of something), swim, jump into cold water, have sex with committed partner, beat Angry Birds, eat a modest-size ice cream cone, etc.
- Do something very outside of normal comfort zone -- go speed dating, sing karaoke, attend a cooking class where you get to make something, go clubbing (don't binge drink or sleep with stranger though; that will just depress you more afterwards), go to a comedy club with friends, go race go-karts, go (safely) fire guns at a shooting range (under supervision of an expert), go to an amateur chess club and play some pickup games, etc.
- Do something even farther outside of normal comfort zone -- attend a renaissance society event, go watch Madrigal Singers perform, make hot chocolate and offer to share with a stranger (in a very safe / campus setting), attend a debate club meeting and attempt to speak, attend a poetry jam or open mic poetry reading. Read something on mic.
- Accept that you are only human, and unles you are God (you're not, are you?) then you will make mistakes. It's part of the human condition.